# Setup IIS for automated webpage installation

Tags: c#, iis-6

I have an installer which places the root folder of my webpage into the inetpub/wwwroot/ directory. I have three issues:

1.) The actual webpage as is it seen in IIS is an application using the DefaultAppPool with classic .net. When it is added to IIS, it is set up as an application, but there is no application name.

2.) On certain machines, the ASP.NET v1.1.4322 web service is not added to IIS. I'm not sure I can add this through code.

3.) My web app requires three ASP.NET web services, two of which are installed by default (v2.0.50727 and v4.0.30319). Once v1.1.4311 is added, the status of all three must be changed to allow. Again, I am unsure if this can be done through code.

All of the above issues are seen in Windows Server 2003 running IIS 6.0. MSDN's page on IIS is rather meek when it comes to these issues, so any help here would be appreciated, even if its a pointer to another forum. Thanks to all in advance!

Comment: Which installer are you using - wix, VS Setup Project, InstallShield? Is it the installer code that sets up the site?